# How to convert /Date(1426066399983)/ to 23:00 Wed Mar 2015 in android

Tags: java, android

i have sent the sentTime of message in sql datable like

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

but when i am getting the sendTime from table it is like /Date(1426066399983)/

so that I want to convert string timestamp like /Date(1426066399983)/ to 23:00 Wed Mar 2015 format how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that 1426066399983 is the milliseconds time? If so something like this will do using the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1426066399983);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy/HH/mm");
String strdate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Something like that should work

Comment: its getting force close

Comment: I need more information than that. What is the stack trace? Or wrap it in a try catch and tell me the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that your date number is a long.

```
long a = 1426066399983;
Date date = new Date((long) a);
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - HH/mm").format(date);
```